# C++ - adding a hashmap to a struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I want a struct that has an `unordered_map` as a member.
I also don't want to type out the type all the time, so I `typedef` it.

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, int> HM;
struct A {
    HM myHm;
}

A *myA = new A();
HM hashmap = new HM(); // empty hashmap
hashmap["1"] = 1;
myA->myHm = hashmap;
```

Of course this isn't correct.

I see examples of people doing `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> HM;`
And then immediately `HM["1"] = 1;`

First of all, I'm used to Java where `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> HM;` is just a type and if I want to add stuff to it, I need to instantiate it with `()`.

It seems that in C++, it's instantiated the moment I write `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> HM;`. Can anyone offer some insight into this?

Second, what is the correct way of doing what I want?

Comment: That code compiles and does what you would expect (well, if you put the code inside a function it would).

Comment: `A mA; HM hashmap;` are sufficient and preferred in C++ to create fully-fledged objects. No `new` means no memory leaks (usually). Also you are creating a hash map as a local variable and then copying it into the hash map in your struct. Why not just use that one directly?

Comment: @JamesPicone I get `conversion from ‘HM*’ to non-scalar type ‘HM’ requested` when I assign `HM()` to `HM hashmap`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same code?

Comment: I have that code in a compiler right now; it definitely behaves. Are you sure you haven't written `new HM()`, or some equivalent?

Comment: @JamesPicone My mistake. I used `new`. It does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you would normally not write this:

```
HM hashmap = HM();
```

That's because what you're doing there is to create an anonymous temporary with `HM()` (the default constructor), then assign it to another one called `hashmap`.  Instead, you can simply do this:

```
HM hashmap;
```

That will equally default-construct a hash map, and avoids any potential unnecessary assignment or double-construction.

Another issue with your existing code is that you use `new` and store the result in a "raw" pointer, but never call `delete` on it.  Instead, you can skip using `new` altogether, and avoid redundancy, like this:

```
A myA; // contains HM
myA.myHm["1"] = 1;
```

This does everything you need in the minimal number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

A way of thinking about things that might help is to think of all variables in C++ as being 'value types', in C# lingo (I don't know what the appropriate Java term is).

This Java is perfectly legal:

```
int foo;
foo = 2;
foo *= 17
```

because 'foo' is just a value, it lives entirely on the stack and doesn't need to be allocated.

In Java, when you declare a variable of a complex type (say, a HashMap) it doesn't live on the stack, and it has to be allocated. In C++, when you declare a variable of a complex type, that's exactly what you get, and it lives on the stack. If you want a reference type, you have to explicitly ask for it.

The term to look for is 'auto variables'. Variables declared inside a function are 'auto variables', they have their constructors called when execution gets to their declaration, and they have their destructors called when their scope is left. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) a link to the appropriate Wikipedia page.

It's a really useful behavior, and it lies behind a common C++ idiom called [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

If you want to call a non-default constructor of the type, you can just add parentheses:

```
SomeType foo(p1, p2);
```

That calls `SomeType::SomeType(p1, p2)` to construct foo.